# substrings from a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have this string

```
str = CTGGCATAACAAGACAAAAACAAAAGCAATAAATGCTGAAAAAACAAAATGCCGTGATCGTTTGTAATACTGGAACATAGTCATGATGAATGAAGGTTTCTGAACCTGAAGAACGACCTGAAAAAGTCAAACCGCAAGAATATCACGACGCAGTGAACCAGAATAGCAACGACGAAAATGTCCAGGAAAAATCCTGGAGTCAGATTCAGGGTTATTCGTTAGTGGCAGGATTACGAAGCGTGGGGCACAGGAGATACATCTCCAGTAAGATGGCAACGTAATCGCGGGCTTCTTTTTTAAGATCAAAAGATTGCGGGGCAAAGAGCCAGTTTTCCATCAGGCCGGAAATATAGCCGCGCATAATAATTGCTGCGCGACGCGTCATTAAATCCGCAGGCAACATTTTCGCTTCAATACAATGTTTTAACGTTTGTTCTATACGGTCATAACTTTCCAGACAGAGATTACGTTGTGCCTGTTGCACAACAGCCATTTCTCCGACAAATTCGCATTTGTGGAATATAATCTCCATCAATAATCGACGCCGTTCTTCTGTCACCGTGGATTCAAGAACATGAATTAATATCTCTCTTAATACTGAGAGTGGATCGCCAGGGAATTTTGCCTGATACTCAAGCTCTAGTTCACCAATATTGGATTCTGACAGTTCCCAGATCTCACTGAACAAATCCGACTTGTCTTTAAAATGCCAGTAGATTGCACCGCGCGTAACGCCAGCTGCTTTTGCAATCTCGCCCAGCGAGGTGGATGATACCCCCTGCTGTGAGAAAAGACGTAGAGCCACATCGAGGATGTGTTGGCGCGTTTCTTGCGCTTCTTGTTTGGTTTTTCGTGCCATATGTTCGTGAATTTACAGGCGTTAGATTTACATACATTTGTGAATGTATGTACCATAGCACGACGATAATATAAACGCAGCAATGGGTTTATTAACTTTTGACCATTGACCAATTTGAAATCGGACACTCGAGGTTTACATA
```

I would like to chop this string in multiple substrings like str[0:19] str[1:20] str[2:21] str[3:22] ..... etc to the end.

Comment: So what have you tried so far with your code? :)

Comment: Just by curiosity, how will you further process this DNA sequence with Python? Never used it for bioinformatics myself ;)

Comment: Do you want all the substrings to be of length == 19?

Comment: my code.. not much i only extract 20 letter, only i want to extrac this sequence to used them like a target of other program, yes all my substring will be the same length

Answer (score 3):

Use string slicing:

```
>>> strs = "CTGGCATAACAAGACAAAAACAAAAGCAATAAATGCTGAAAAAACAAAATGCCGTGATCGTTTGTAATACTGGAACATAGTCATGATGAATGAAGGTTTCTGAACCTGAAGAACGACCTGAAAAAGTCAAACCGCAAGAATATCACGACGCAGTGAACCAGAATAGCAACGACGAAAATGTCCAGGAAAAATCCTGGAGTCAGATTCAGGGTTATTCGTTAGTGGCAGGATTACGAAGCGTGGGGCACAGGAGATACATCTCCAGTAAGATGGCAACGTAATCGCGGGCTTCTTTTTTAAGATCAAAAGATTGCGGGGCAAAGAGCCAGTTTTCCATCAGGCCGGAAATATAGCCGCGCATAATAATTGCTGCGCGACGCGTCATTAAATCCGCAGGCAACATTTTCGCTTCAATACAATGTTTTAACGTTTGTTCTATACGGTCATAACTTTCCAGACAGAGATTACGTTGTGCCTGTTGCACAACAGCCATTTCTCCGACAAATTCGCATTTGTGGAATATAATCTCCATCAATAATCGACGCCGTTCTTCTGTCACCGTGGATTCAAGAACATGAATTAATATCTCTCTTAATACTGAGAGTGGATCGCCAGGGAATTTTGCCTGATACTCAAGCTCTAGTTCACCAATATTGGATTCTGACAGTTCCCAGATCTCACTGAACAAATCCGACTTGTCTTTAAAATGCCAGTAGATTGCACCGCGCGTAACGCCAGCTGCTTTTGCAATCTCGCCCAGCGAGGTGGATGATACCCCCTGCTGTGAGAAAAGACGTAGAGCCACATCGAGGATGTGTTGGCGCGTTTCTTGCGCTTCTTGTTTGGTTTTTCGTGCCATATGTTCGTGAATTTACAGGCGTTAGATTTACATACATTTGTGAATGTATGTACCATAGCACGACGATAATATAAACGCAGCAATGGGTTTATTAACTTTTGACCATTGACCAATTTGAAATCGGACACTCGAGGTTTACATA"
>>> substrings = [strs[i:i+19] for i in xrange(len(strs))]
>>> substrings
['CTGGCATAACAAGACAAAA', 'TGGCATAACAAGACAAAAA', 'GGCATAACAAGACAAAAAC',...]
```

Comment: But wouldn't it return strings of smaller length (less than 19) in the end?

Comment: @AnkurAnkan I've asked the OP about that, if that's the case then your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
chopped_str = []
for i in range(0, len(str)-19):
   chopped_str.append(str[i:i+19])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you searching to extract all the sequences of 19 nucleotides from the chain this will do it:

```
>>> SEQ_LEN = 20
>>> [strs[i:i+SEQ_LEN] for i in xrange(len(strs)-SEQ_LEN)]
```

However, it is not very memory efficient since if will produce the list of all the sub-sequences. What is it for?

---

An alternative approach for processing each sub-sequence of N nucleotides could be:

```
for seq in (strs[i:i+SEQ_LEN] for i in xrange(len(strs)-SEQ_LEN)):
    do_something_with(seq)
```

For your specific problem, `do_something_with` will be mostly *update the PWM with the nucleotide positions*. If you have difficulties with that, feel free to post an other question ;)

Comment: i need all the sequences, because i want to test this sequences with a matrix (pwm) and calculate a score with each one, and one of this sequences is a real positive and i want to know the score with all other and then classffy

Comment: I don't know if the sequence you posted in your question is the "real" one -- but for (much) longer sequences, it should be more memory efficient to process the sub-sequences one by one to build the PWM -- instead of extracting all of them first.